# Amazon S3: How to safely upload multiple files?

Tags: amazon-s3, eventual-consistency

I have two client programs which are using S3 to communicate some information. That information is a list of files.

Let's call the clients the "uploader" and "downloader":

The uploader does something like this:

- upload file A
- upload file B
- upload file C
- upload a SUCCESS marker file

The downloader does something lie this:

- check for SUCCESS marker

  - if found, download A, B, C.
  - else, get data from somewhere else

and both of these programs are being run periodically. The uploader will populate a new directory when it is done, and the downloader will try to get the latest versions of A,B,C available.

Hopefully the intent is clear — I don't want the downloader to see a partial view, but rather get all of A,B,C or skip that directory.

**However**, I don't think that works, as written. Thanks to eventual consistency, the uploader's PUTs could be reordered into:

- upload file B
- upload a SUCCESS marker file
- upload file A
- ...

And at this moment, the downloader might run, see the SUCCESS marker, and assume the directory is populated (which it is not).

So what's the right approach, here?

One idea is for the uploader to first upload A,B,C, then repeatedly check that the files are stored, and only after it sees all of them, then finally write the SUCCESS marker.

Would that work?

Comment: Could you use SQS to send a SUCCESS marker message (instead of an S3 marker file) from your uploader program to the downloader program after A, B, and C have been uploaded successfully?

Comment: @AdilB: Ideally I'd like to avoid adding more dependencies. But even if i do what you say, how does it help? There is no guarantee that after having received the SQS message I am now able to find all of A,B,C in S3, is there? That's the whole 'eventual' in 'eventual consistency', as I understand it.

Comment: Actually, looking at the S3 docs again: `Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat.` The caveat is: as long as you aren't planning on overwriting files A, B, or C after uploading them, they should be immediately consistent to the downloader program along with your SUCCESS file marker.

Comment: @AdilB almost true.  If you check for an object's existence before it exists, you lose immediate consistency on creation of that object... so the appearance of the success file might be delayed, but as long as you don't check any of the others, first, you're good.

Comment: Yes, I've read these docs as well. The problem is that my uploader and downloader processes run independently of each other. I don't have a way to be sure that I only read the marker file after it is written, so I don't have a way to get read-after-write consistency. And once I'm in eventual consistency territory, couldn't the marker show up first, even if it was uploaded last? I'm not clear if there are any guarantees about the relationship between the (eventually consistent) marker and the A,B,C files' appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon similar issue in my project.
If the intention is to guarantee cross-file consistency (between files A,B,C) the only possible solution (purely within s3) is:

1) to put them as NEW objects

2) do not explicitly check for existence using HEAD or GET request prior to the put.

These two constraints above are required for fully consistent read-after-write behavior (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-s3-introduces-new-usability-enhancements/)

Each time you update the files, you need to generate a unique prefix (folder) name and put this name into your marker file (the manifest) which you are going to UPDATE.

The manifest will have a stable name but will be eventually consistent. Some clients may get the old version and some may get the new one.
The old manifest will point to the old “folder” and the new one will point the new “folder”. Thus each client will read only old files or only new files but never mixed, so cross file consistency will be achieved. Still different clients may end up having different versions. If the clients keep pulling the manifest and getting updated on change, they will eventually become consistent too.

Possible solution for client inconsistency is to move manifest meta data out of s3 into a consistent database (such as dynamo db)

A few obvious caveats with pure  s3 approach:

1) requires full set of files to be uploaded each time (incremental updates are not possible)

2) needs eventual cleanup of old obsolete folders

3) clients need to keep pulling manifest to get updated

4) clients may be inconsistent between each other

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this single copies in S3.  Each file (A B C) will have prepended to it a unique hash or version code [e.g. md5sum generated from the concatenation of all three files.]

In addition the hash value will be uploaded to the bucket as well into a separate object.

When consuming the files, first read the hash file and compare to the last hash successfully consumed. If changed, then read the files and check the hash value within each. If they all match, the data is valid and may be used. If not, the downloaded files should be disgarded and downloaded again (after a suitable delay)..

This will catch the occassional race condition between write and read across multiple objects.

This works because the hash is repeated in all objects.  The hash file is actually optional, serving as a low-cost and fast short cut for determining if the data is updated.